# How to find $x + y + z$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, exponentiation

> **Q.** If $x^{1/3} + y^{1/3} + z^{1/3} = 0$, then
>
> (A) $x + y + z = 3 xyz$
>
> (B) $x + y + z = 0 $
>
> (C) $( x + y + z)^3= 27 xyz$
>
> (D)$ x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 0$

---

What I've done:
$(x^{1/3} + y^{1/3} + z^{1/3})^3 = 0^3$

$=> (x^{1/3} + y^{1/3})^3 + z+3(x^{1/3} + y^{1/3})z(x^{1/3} + y^{1/3}+z^{1/3})=0$

$=> (x^{1/3} + y^{1/3})^3 + z=0$

Now what??

Comment: You could probably eliminate most/all of the alternatives by plugging in a numerical example.

Answer (score 5):

use this

> $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac)$$
>
> so if $a+b+c=0$,then we have
>   $$a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$$
>
> then if $$x^{\frac{1}{3}}+y^{\frac{1}{3}}+z^{\frac{1}{3}}=0$$
>   $$\Longrightarrow x+y+z=3(xyz)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
>   so
>   $$(x+y+z)^3=27xyz$$
>   \begin{align*}&a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc \\
> &=(a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3+c^3)-(3abc+3a^2b+3ab^2)\\ 
> &=[(a+b)^3+c^3]-3ab(a+b+c)\\
> &=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+2ab-ac-bc+c^2)-3ab(a+b+c)\\ 
> &=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab-3ab-ac-bc)\\
> &=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac)
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thanks- but could you also show me how you get the first equation. What identity is that derived from?

Comment: @Ghost That is not something taken from a formula. It's a thing you notice when expanding the RHS.